# How to implement a daemon stoppable polling thread in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

From my understanding there is no such out-of-the-box solution in the python stdlib.

The solution has to have the following characteristics:

- Start the thread as daemon with a target function and optional arguments
- Have polling: the thread should rerun the target every X seconds
- Allow easy and graceful stopping: Not breaking target execution midway
- Expose the ability to stop from outside the program it belongs to, in particular be able to stop the thread from testing code.
- Allow thread restarting after stop (or pseudo-restarting with a new thread)

I ran across a couple of suggestions on SO, but would like to aggregate any collected knowledge here (i will contribute in that in a follow-up answer), so that any new or alternative or additional ideas be heard.

Answer (score 4):

My proposal uses the `threading` library, as it is advertised as more high level than `thread`.

A middle ground is this solution, found from other SO answer:

```
def main():
   t_stop= threading.Event()
   t = threading.Thread(target=thread, args=(1, t_stop))
   t.daemon = True
   t.start()

   time.sleep(duration)
   #stop the thread
   t_stop.set()

def thread(arg, stop_event):
    while(not stop_event.is_set()):
        # Code to execute here
        stop_event.wait(time)
```

This, unfortunately, requires us to have the `t_stop` object handy when testing -in order to stop the thread- and that handle to the object is not designed to be exposed.

A solution would be to add `t` and `t_stop` handles in a top level or global dictionary somewhere, for the testing code to reach.

Another solution (copied and improved from somewhere) is use of the following:

```
def main():
    t = DaemonStoppableThread(sleep_time, target=target_function,
                              name='polling_thread',
                              args=(arg1, arg2))
    t.start()

# Stopping code from a test
def stop_polling_threads():
    threads = threading.enumerate()
    polling_threads = [thread for thread in threads
                       if 'polling_thread' in thread.getName()]
    for poll_thread in polling_threads:
        poll_thread.stop()


class DaemonStoppableThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, sleep_time, target=None,  **kwargs):
        super(DaemonStoppableThread, self).__init__(target=target, **kwargs)
        self.setDaemon(True)
        self.stop_event = threading.Event()
        self.sleep_time = sleep_time
        self.target = target

    def stop(self):
        self.stop_event.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self.stop_event.isSet()

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopped():
            if self.target:
                self.target()
            else:
                raise Exception('No target function given')
            self.stop_event.wait(self.sleep_time)
```

As good as these solutions may be, none of them face the restarting of the polling target function.

I avoided using the expression "restarting thread", as I understand that python threads cannot be restarted, so a new thread will have to be used to allow for this "pseudo-restarting"

EDIT:

To improve on the above, a solution to start/stop the polling target multiple times:

```
class ThreadManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
       self.thread = None

    def start_thread(self):
        if not self.thread or not self.thread.is_alive():
            self.thread = DaemonStoppableThread(sleep_time=5, target=some_func, args=(1, 2))
            self.thread.start()
        return 'thread running'

    def stop_thread(self):
        if self.thread and self.thread.is_alive():
            self.thread.stop()
            return 'thread stopped'
        else:
            return 'dead thread'

    def check_thread(self):
        if self.thread and self.thread.is_alive():
            return 'thread alive'
        else:
            return 'dead_thread'
```